# Accidentally changed an IPv4 setting on Synology NAS Cannot access it anymore

Tags: networking, nas, ipv4, synology, synology-diskstation

I have a Synology NAS which was working fine - for the usage I was making of it : backup - but it wasn't connected to the internet. I was able to access it via the browser GUI or in windows (via \DISKSTATION ), but I couldn't update, or download plugins/app for it. It simply was not getting an internet connection.

So yesterday at the end of the day I started "trying" to change the IPV4 after reading things about it - and that's where I messed up, I changed the 2 default values in a setting somewhere, which were exactly these: 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 ( these looks like default, classic addresses apparently )

I thought I needed to put the IPV4 address I found with ipconfig : 169.2**.***.***)

When I clicked on save, there was some loading bar showing up, and suddenly got a "page not found, no internet" error message when it was loading. Couldn't access it via Windows anymore, either.

How could I put back the 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 values for that setting? I think it was somewhere located in the "Network" option tab, here a screenshot I found of these parameters ( looking very much like what I changed, but just not on the IPv4 tab ).

[image: screenshot found elsewhere - possible location for the settings change made for IPV4]

Comment: `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` are IPv4 addresses that belong to Google DNS servers. Under the hood computers actually don't understand those pretty domain names like superuser.com and so they ask DNS servers to translate those into IP addresses. Changing DNS servers in your Synology will not make it unreachable as they only affect how the Synology resolves domain names of systems on the internet.

Comment: How is your Synology connected to your network? You say it doesn't have internet access yet you are able to connect to it in your network. If it's connected to a router you could check that out to find the Synology's IPv6 address and enter that to access its web interface.

Comment: It is connected via an ethernet cable to my tower PC

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Synology NASes have a [networking reset procedure](https://www.synology.com/en-us/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/General_Setup/How_to_reset_my_Synology_NAS):

> 1. Locate the **RESET** button on your Synology NAS.
> 2. Use a paper clip to gently press and hold down the **RESET** button for about 4 seconds until you hear a beep, and then release the button immediately.
>
> [...]
>
> 8. Disable the admin account by first signing in with your administrator account, and then going to **Control Panel** > **User** > the **User** tab. Double click on `admin` and tick the **Disable this account** checkbox. Click OK.
> 9. The `admin` account status should now be Disabled.

Steps 8 and 9 are necessary because this procedure will also re-enable the default `admin` account, which should be disabled for security under normal circumstances.

The RESET button is typically at the back, in a small hole. You can press it with a paperclip.

Comment: That fixed it yes. I've reset to the default network settings.

Answer (score 7):

Okay, if your Synology still has its default IPv6 setup you can try to find it via the IPv6 Neighbor Discovery Protocol. The NDP list shows only devices, which had communicated to each other. So we need to issue a multicast ping. This will trigger an answer from all members of the subnet.

We need the interface name for this. In Windows it is a number, which can be found in ipconfig. Open PowerShell and attach the output to your question:

```
ipconfig /all
```

Let's say it returns the following link local IPv6 address:

```
fe80::9059:69ff:fed5:8dc9%3
```

In this case the interface ID is 3. It can be found behind the IPv6 address, separated with a %.

Run the ping

```
ping ff02::1%3
```

Then list the neighbors

```
netsh interface ipv6 show neighbors
```

Now there should be at least one entry in the list where the IPv6 address starts with fe80:. This should be the address of the connected device - your Synology. Enter that in your internet browser with the same port (:5000/:5001).

Comment: Very intelligent approach using IPv6 NDP!